# Очікувальний чи очікуваний результат?

Tags: вживання-слів

Як правильно сформулювати словосполучення ***"очікувальний результат"*** чи ***"очікуваний результат"***? Бачила вживання обох виразів.

СУМ-11

> ***[Очікувальний](http://sum.in.ua/s/ochikuvaljnyj)*** а, е. Те саме, що вичікувальний. *Проти нього з очікувальними обличчями сиділи Дорош і Оксен* (Григорій
>   Тютюнник, Вир, 1964, 171).
>
> ***[Очікуваний](http://sum.in.ua/s/ochikuvanyj)***  а, е. Дієпр. пас. теп. і мин. ч. до очікувати. *Тим часом так нетерпляче очікувана відповідь не надходить* (Михайло Коцюбинський, III, 1956, 119); *Тільки радість буває очікуваною, бо
>   людина щодня її для себе виборює, а лихо приходить неждано* (Микола
>   Руденко, Остання шабля, 1959, 389)

Answer (score 2):

**Очікувальний/вичікувальний** - той, що знаходиться в стані очікування на щось:

> Панасович оглянув присутніх і зустрівся з зацікавленими,
>   вичікувальними і, здається, трохи насмішкуватими поглядами.

Тобто, у тексті люди чекали на щось.

**Очікуваний** - той, та чи те, на що чекали:

> Тим часом так нетерпляче очікувана відповідь не надходить

Очікувана, тобто на неї чекають.

Отже, коли ми чекаємо на щось, то ми можемо знаходитися в очікувальному стані, а коли ми чогось довго хотіли і отримали цього, то ми можемо сказати, що ми отримали очікуваний результат.

Про все це можна дізнатися із СУМу, просто потрібно уважніше перечитати інформацію.

Answer (score 1):

[Є три види процесових](http://tc.terminology.lp.edu.ua/TK_Wisnyk676/TK_wisnyk676_kocherha_pilec'kyj.htm), тобто віддієслівних прикметників, вони виражають:

> 1. здатність бути підданим дії (інтеґровний, йонізовний, (з)руйновний, синтезовний, фільтровний)
> 2. призначення виконувати дію (інтеґрувальний, йонізувальний, синтезувальний, фільтрувальний)
> 3. здатність виконувати дію (йонізівний, руйнівний, фільтрівний)

Тобто *очікувальний* означає призначення до певної функції/дії.

Comment: не могли б ви таки пояснити, як саме ця інформація застосовується до цього питання, тобто, виходячи з того, які є види процесових прикметників, який з двох наведених у питання прикметників краще використати у словосполученні, яке викликає у запитувачки сумніви? Розумію, що хочеться, щоб всі думали самі, але не всі відвідувачі мають час на роздумування, тож було б добре мати відповідь у готовій формі, а не як заклик потім додуматись самостійно.

Comment: Про три види процесових прикметників — це дуже доречно. Але мені здається, в цьому випадку (зокрема в прикладах, наведених у запитанні, про _очікувальні обличчя_), _очікувальний_ — це все-таки більше «характерний для очікування», ніж «призначений для очікування». Хоча й «призначений для очікування» теж може бути — наприклад, _[очікувальний зал](//www.google.com/search?q=%22очікувальний+зал%22)_ (хоч формально його чомусь частіше називають _[залом очікування](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Зала_очікування)_).

Answer (score 0):

Я вважаю, що ваше запитання вже містить відповідь:

- *Очікувальний* / *вичікувальний* — той, що повʼязаний з чеканням;
- *Очікуваний* — той, **чого** чекають, **на що** очікують.

<sub>(Community Wiki присвячується Капітанові Очевидність :-)</sub>